# CLANG compiler generates an error stating that "the clang compiler does not support 'armv4t-none-unknown-eabi'"

Tags: clang, clang++, clang-format, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to compile using Clang compiler of version V8.1.0. I got a compilation error stating that "the clang compiler does not support 'armv4t-none-unknown-eabi'".
1- I need to know if there is a new version that supports this architecture.
2- If not, is there a way to compile using this compiler somehow ?